# Style edges of layer shapefiles to have thicker borders

Tags: qgis, polygon, style, borders

I have two layers I'm working with here, both of North Carolina. One is "townships" the other is "counties". I want the counties shapes to have thick edges with no fill-in color.

I couldn't find anything on this after a google search so decided to ask.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is pretty basic stuff, what you're looking for is covered here:
http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-styling-vector-data-in-qgis.html

Found by doing a Google search for "qgis polygon style"

Answer (score 4):

For a non linked answer, right click on the layer name and select Properties>Style tab and set the Fill style to No Brush and Outline width to a larger number, see image below:

[image]